# Setting an Instance's Variable While Returning it

Tags: java

Just curious about little something that came to mind, but I haven't been able to find an answer to it by searching.  Is it possible to return an instance with the `return` keyword and also set a variable within that instance in the same line?

For example, I tried doing:

```
public Person randomPersonHeight(Person person){
     Random r = new Random();
     return person.height = 5+(r.nextFloat()*1.5);//Imperial Measurements baby!
}
```

I wanted to set the persons height AND return the person in one swoop.  But no surprise that didn't work.  Of course it isn't important that I can do it in the single line.  And, just wont stand for anything less!..  But, I found myself wanting to know there was any expression or different format that would make it possible.

Comment: No. There is no way to write that expression on one line. Use two.

Comment: Well, if your `Person` has a constructor that takes a height, you could `return new Person(newHeight)`. But that's only if you have the appropriate constructor (and if you don't need anything else than the height).

Comment: it is possible: [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) - see my comment to [Henning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57358003/85421) if you really want an ugly way to do it (not very realistic/serious)

Comment: Yep, I figured there wasn't a way to do this in a traditional way, because it didn't make logical sense to me but I'm glad I could ask everyone real quick if anyone else knew some niche magical expression I didn't know.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't to that.

There's a common idiom where *setter methods* return the object itself, to make something like this possible. But you can't do it with just the language's native operators.

---

Except, of course, if you write

```
 person.height = 5+(r.nextFloat()*1.5); return person;
```

But if you ever let a code autoformatter near that, it probably won't survive ...

Comment: "*you can't do it with just the language's native operators*" - do not underestimate developers imagination.... `return (person.height = 5+(r.nextFloat()*1.5)) > 0 ? person : null;` (and ability to make unreadable code [:-) )

Comment: [15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) is a native operator, Optional is more like a class... and sure not a Person

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That code made me laugh by it's creativity.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers talked about setters but I think they misinterpreted your question to be about coding conventions (what you *should* do) while, if I understand you correctly, you asked about the Java language itself (what you *can* do).

Returning a value and setting it at the same time is no problem with the Java language.

## Example

```
class Test
{
    int sum;

    public int sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return (sum=a+b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println(new Test().sum(1,2));
    }

}
```

Comment: "Returning a value and setting it at the same time is no problem with the Java language" with the **heavy** caveat that the return type must equal the thing that you are setting. Which he is not. He is setting a double and hoping to return a person.

Comment: @Michael: You are right, I misinterpreted the question myself.